# Krypton Ribbon add items to the file tab

Tags: vb.net, krypton-toolkit

Sure I am being a bit thick but can anyone tell me how I can add a save button to the Krypton Ribbon file tab. For all other tabs I can drag from the toolbox but I cant for the life of me figure out how to add a button or anything else to the file tab. I'm using vb.net and cant find anything on google explaining how to do this at all

Many Thanks

Gibbo

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, was being daft, in the properties of the ribbon you can add a button in the RibbonAppButton to AppButton MenuItems/ AppButtonSpecs.

Then just add an onclick event in the code

```
Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
```

Thanks for looking